# Listen voice messages on server A from server B with asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, voicemail

I have `RealTime` asterisk with 3 servers. In database I hold `sippears` only and `voicemail` boxes. Voicemail messages are stored on the system FILE_STORAGE.

Server A and B are for calls and sip registrations and Server C is dundi.
Currently everything work fine.. I can call from Server A to Server B. The problem is when I leave message to number who is busy and registered on Server B.. then this number disconnect and register on Server A -> he can't listen the messages because it is stored on Server B..

How can I make any user to be able to listen his messages no matter on which server are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have alot of options, most of each in clustering area.

Simplest options are:

- Glusterfs setup on both server, voicemail in glusterfs directory. This one do failover
- NFS/samba share on both servers.
- mysql master-master replication, use ODBC_STORAGE, put all voicemails in db. This one is recommended if you also want easy access from web interface to your voice files and simple search/lookup/get message. Highly recommended use innodb tables and optimized mysql config.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I don't want to save messages into database so at this point ODBC_STORAGE is not an option. If I trying to use one of other two options do I need something additional configuration on Asterisk side or this is only on Linux and file sharing side?

Comment: And one more question. If I use NFS what I must share? Whole `/var/spool/voicemail/..` directory?

Comment: In all cases you should share voicemail folder. It is /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/ if you not changed something in /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way just for to be able to listen them no matter on which of both servers user is registered is NFS and mounting for example `/var/spool/asterisk/`. In this case you need to install some additional components. 
Here is great tutorial how can you done this:
[How to configure an NFS server and mount NFS shares - Ubuntu](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-configure-a-nfs-server-and-mount-nfs-shares-on-ubuntu-14.04)

Another way if you can make master-slave with two servers in cluster and using [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) . Then you can sync every X minutes/hours/days folder to remote server to keep them in case of failure.

```
rsync -a local_dir/ user@remote-host-ip:/path/to/dir
```

Comment: This one is EXTREAMLY bad idea. If you do sync like that, you have no ability remove message.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just pointing him to some fast solutions. From where he can start.